# Google App Engine Java API

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am Planning to Create a Website using servlet and JSP. The website is about web gallery. Its my project. I am using "Blobstore" for storing and retrieving the image. I have to create a Album and have to store images in it.

Questions araised in my mind:

1. How to store multiple images under one name.
   For example, "Album-1" This is the name.. How to store images under this name.
2. I need the list of albums in the datastore to be displayed in webpage. If I click any it have to show images under that album.

Can anyone give solution or hint for that with possible codes..

Comment: You need to create an entity separately which will store all the images BlobKey and imageURL (ImageService API) and u can group all the images in this entity and store images as a list object inside your album object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not be an elegant solution but you can think of doing this as follows :

If you want to group images uploaded to BlobStore in different albums, you will need to get hold of the blob-keys and logically connect them to the album names.

You can think of having a form which asks the user to enter an album name and then he has an option to upload images and on submit it gets uploaded to the blobstore.

For Example :

Say if you upload 3 images with the names **Image_1.jpg** , **Image_2.jpg** , **Image_3.jpg** and provided the album name as **Demo Album** and after upload you got 3 blob-keys **key_1** , **key_2** , **key_3**, so now you need to create 3 separate entities in the datastore with kind say **Image_Album** and with property **blob_key** and **album_name**.

You would have three entries for the Entity kind **Image_Album** as :

```
     blob_key   album_name    

     Key_1      Demo Album
     Key_2      Demo Album
     Key_3      Demo Album
```

Like this you can have n number of entries and while displaying the albums, you can query the datastore for all distinct album_name for the entity kind Image_Album which will be your number of Albums present. Fetch all the blob-keys for each distinct album name and serve them from blobstore on your web page.

**EDIT:**

After you have uploaded multiple images to Blobstore through a form then in the upload handler servlet you will have all the keys stored in a map and you can access them like this :

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);

  for (String key : blobs.keySet()) 
    {     
        for (BlobKey value : blobs.get(key)) 
        {
           String x =value.getKeyString()
        }
     }
```

Comment: And one more thing. I know how to get a single key from blobstore using java. But how to get multiple keys. For example, for Image_1.jpg,Image_1.jpg,Image_1.jpg there will be 3 keys. How to get those 3 keys?

Comment: I have edited my answer to accommodate your subsequent question. Please change the title of the question to something more specific to Blobstore.